# Can you put an inline expression in a ReportViewer text box?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have a Text Box with some text in it.  I want to be able to replace some of the text with a date value expression. The value will come from a Dataset Field.  I have tried a few things (putting a Text Box with the expression over this Text Box, used the {{Expr}} tag, and a couple other things) with no luck.

Just wondering if this is possible and/or if someone came up with a simple solution that works?

EDIT, I want to do something like this (where SCARED is an expression and not static):

Today I found a mouse and it **SCARED** me so badly that I passed out.

I would like to maintain the formatting (bold, underlined, etc) as well as insert an expression.  At this point I can only do one or the other.

Comment: Have tried this: right click on the textbox and choose the `Expression` and ...

Comment: well I never thought of adding all this text (there is a lot) inside an expression.  This is a good idea, let me test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add an expression to the text and at the same time preserve formatting (bolding and underlining) I chained three Text Boxes together. The expression text will have it's own Text Box that is formatted.  You can add an expression mid text in the expression (right click on the Text Box, etc) but you cannot make only the expression bold (at least that I found).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the `Textbox` and choose the Expression. You will see that there are lost of options available. Also there are lost of categorized functions that can be applied on fields and parameters and ...

Comment: I am pretty familiar with the expression builder.  Your solution pointed me to trying to put all the text in a single expression, including the actual expression.  However, now I cannot use any of the formatting like bolding, underlining, etc.  Just simple text.